# Graphql Schema type error indicating duplicate types, which it does not have?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I have now completely wasted my evening trying to work this one out but am beyond an answer, even after multiple searches.

I have my server which grabs my folders of '.graphql' files and merges them into one large one which I pass along with my resolvers into 'makeExecutableSchema()' as seen below

```
        const folders      = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, './api'));
        const allResolvers = [];
        let typeDefs       = '';

        folders.forEach(folder => {
          if (folder !== 'directive') {
            typeDefs = typeDefs.concat(requireText(`./api/${folder}/${folder}.graphql`, require));
            const { resolver } = require(`./api/${folder}/${folder}.resolvers`);
            allResolvers.push(resolver);
          }
        });

        const resolvers = _.merge(allResolvers);
        return makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers});
```

Now i am constantly getting an error

```
    Error: Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Address".
        at invariant (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\invariant.js:19:11)
        at typeMapReducer (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:216:58)
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:237:36
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at typeMapReducer (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:232:51)
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at new GraphQLSchema (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:122:28)
        at Object.extendSchema (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql\utilities\extendSchema.js:161:10)
        at buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\schemaGenerator.js:186:28)
        at _generateSchema (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\schemaGenerator.js:97:18)
        at Object.makeExecutableSchema (C:\100hotwater\src\server\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\schemaGenerator.js:110:20)
        at Object.exports.allSchema (C:\100hotwater\src\server\helpers.js:22:28)
        at Server.graphQl (C:\100hotwater\src\server\index.js:28:34)
        at new Server (C:\100hotwater\src\server\index.js:17:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\100hotwater\src\server\index.js:42:19)
```

This schema most definitely does not contain duplicates though as seen below of it printed out right before entering the "makeExecutableSchema"()" function.

```
      type Lead {
        _id: String
        owner: User
        address: Address
        steps: [Step]
      }

      type Mutation {
        createLead(
          owner: String!
          address: Address
          steps: [Step]
        ): Lead
      }

      type Address {
        lat: Int
        lng: Int
        formattedAddress: String
      }

      type Step {
        goto: String
        key: String
        str: String
      }

      type User {
        _id: String
        email: String
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        mobile: Int
        phone: Int
        billingAddress: String
        password: String
        leads: [Lead]
      }

      type Query {
        signedInUser: User
        userByEmail(email: String!): User # @isAuthenticated
      }

      extend type Mutation {
        signIn(email: String!, password: String!): SignInResponse!
        createUser(
          email: String!
          firstName: String!
          lastName: String
          mobile: Int
          billingAddress: String
          password: String
        ): User
      }

      type SignInResponse {
        token: String
        refreshToken: String
      }
```

I noticed in the file "node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:216:58" it seems to loop through the typings twice and obviously catching the Address twice in the check and posting the error but i'm still unsure where to go from here. Simple errors like this in Graphql is making it really hard to love.

Any help is appreciated.

## The Fix

In short thanks to Dan below, I was defining the Address type and using it for both my Input (Mutation) and my Output (Query - Lead). What I didn't realise at the time was that you needed to define types & inputs differently. The working .graphql schema below.

```
      type Lead {
        _id: String
        owner: User
        address: Address
        steps: [Step]
      }

      type Address {
        lat: Int
        lng: Int
        formattedAddress: String
      }

      type Mutation {
        createLead(
          owner: String!
          address: AddressInput 
          steps: [Step]
        ): Lead
      }

      input AddressInput {
        lat: Int
        lng: Int
        formattedAddress: String
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what one of your resolver modules looks like, but I suspect you meant to do something like this:

```
const resolvers = _.merge(...allResolvers) // note the spread operator
```

Otherwise, calling `merge` is not actually doing anything and your `resolvers` property ends up being an array instead of an object.

EDIT: Didn't notice it on first glace, but you're using types as inputs. If you want to use an object with the same shape as the `Address` type, you have to define a separate input type for it:

```
type Address {
  lat: Int
  lng: Int
  formattedAddress: String
}

input AddressInput {
  lat: Int
  lng: Int
  formattedAddress: String
}
```

Types cannot be used for inputs and inputs cannot be used for types. If we were defining the schema programatically, we'd normally see an error to that effect. Evidently generating the schema from SDL doesn't generate the same error. If you add the appropriate input types for Address and Step, your schema should generate correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel this actually was an issue, and have just fixed, but the Multiple types problem still exists, unfortunately.

Comment: @22Ryann Odd. Do you have a repo link you could share? It's tough to know what could be off without seeing more of the underlying code.

Comment: in src/server/src/helpers.ts

Comment: Daniel, thanks for taking the time. I will look more into this evening and change my files. I am actually referring back to some other code I have where I have used types in a different situation and it seems to be working obviously wrongly. I&#39;ll try and possibly post it to try and get your take on it if you don&#39;t mind

Comment: Getting this now Daniel, trying to create new lead, 

" The type of Lead.address must be Output Type but got: AddressInput."

Comment: Like the error suggests, you can't use inputs where a type is expected. You have to have both a *type* for address to use for fields and an *input* for address to use for arguments

Comment: Thanks, Dan, finally understanding the context of how to define the schema properly. It seems a little odd to have an input and a type basically identical. I have it working finally. Thanks again for the time you have spent here.

Comment: It's important to understand that while they can look the same in SDL, `makeExecutableSchema` turns types and inputs into `GraphQLObjectType`s and `GraphQLInputObjectType`s, respectively, which have different properties and are used differently. For example, only types can extend interfaces, or be part of unions, or have arguments on their fields. Only inputs can have default values.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue.

For months we have had the following in our schema

type WindData {
N: windData!
NE: windData!
E: windData!
SE: windData!
S: windData!
SW: windData!
W: windData!
NW: windData!
}

type windData {
isAlarm: Boolean!
value: Float!
}

A few days ago the schema build start failing with

```
Schema has the following errors: - Schema contains duplicate type names.
```

Appears that case is no longer adhered to so we had to go look for any types that mixed case and make the names unique

A change in behaviour from AWS Appsync....

Answer (score -2):

Just had the same issue fixed we had two input and type with the same name just different case, it worked for many months up to today. Took me forever to find it because I thought it was a recent change on our side but it wasnt.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31244546)